# SVG - Performance Issues on Tablet

Tags: performance, svg, tablet

An SVG based [Interactive Map](http://demo.thebambergergroup.com/map/murray-hill/nyc) is having serious performance issues on tablet. Any suggestions on how to optimize performance for a page that renders many SVG graphics - specifically tablet based issues? Is use of a JS library like Canvas helpful?

Comment: What do you not like about the performance? Initial render or show/hide latency? Strip it down to a minimal test case that you can post - as stated too broad & is closeworthy. (Wild guesstimate: this is unlikely to be an SVG issue. The SVG's are rendering ok at least on iOS/iPad Air 2 and there is nothing obviously bad about the path definitions. Probably something screwy in the CSS or JavaScript. )

Comment: Thanks - I've narrowed the question.  There are severe loading time issues on tablet that do not exist on desktop.